# Counting the number of relationships foreach Trip

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database composed with this pattern :

```
(start)-[:Trip]->(end)
```

I want to return the number of trips between  the start and the end node and that on each different Trip((start)-[r]->(end)).

how to do that in Cypher ?

this is what i have tried :

```
 MATCH p=(n)-[r]->()
 WITH COLLECT(p) as X
 UNWIND X.r as y
 return count(y)
```

## Update my question

let's suppose
Trip =

```
     (start_node)-[relationship]->(end_node)
```

example :

```
(Tunis)-[r1]->(Sfax)
(Tunis)-[r2]->(Sfax)
(Tunis)-[r3]->(Sousse)
(Tunis)-[r4]->(Sousse)
(Tunis)-[r5]->(Sousse)
```

=>
The number of trips between (Tunis) AND (Sfax) is 2

The number of trips between (Tunis) AND (Sousse) is 3

that's what i want.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i  tried to use foreach but that didn't works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use the aggregator operator `count` :

```
MATCH (start)-[:Trip]->(end)
RETURN start, end, count(*)
```

Comment: no , that return the count for all the trips, i want foreach different trip count the number of relationships

Comment: ` i want foreach different trip count the number of trips` : there is too many `trip` for me, can you explain it more clearly please ?

Comment: @A.HADDAD You might want to test this one out, I believe it's correct. Keep in mind that aggregations in Neo4j use the non-aggregation variables as the grouping key, which provides the context over what you are grouping over. This query means that for each distinct start and end node, it will give you the number of occurrences, so one of your result rows would be `Tunis, Sfax, 2`.